# How to match content between "<!--" and "|-->"?

Tags: regex

```
<!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png|-->
<img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png" alt="***" title="***"  />
<!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla bla <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/2.png|-->
<img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/2.png" alt="***" title="***"  />
<!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/3.png|-->
<img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/3.png" alt="***" title="***"  />
<!--dle_image_end-->
```

From above example I need to get `^<!--dle_image_begin:(.*)|-->$`, but it returns all the string.

Comment: Yes, that's because `.*` greedily matches zero or more non-EOL characters.

Comment: This is even not a full regex pattern you have here. Nor have you shared the code that shells the regexp action here. So we can not tell you much what you are (potentially) all doing wrong here. Moar code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` matches `|` as well. So regex will go to last position to find `|-->`, this is called greedy. A very common mistake, it's often asked about here on SO.

As simple way to deal with that:

```
^<!--dle_image_begin:([^|]*)\|-->
                      ^^^^  ^    ^
                        |   |    |
           negative class   |    |
                  escape pipe    |
                    dollar is gone
```

Negative character class: All but `|` do match. So will stop at first `|-->` found instead. Regex is a language of it's own, you need to learn next to PHP. It follows it's own rules. Practice makes perfect.

Comment: I believe the OP intended to escape the `|` on `|-->` but forgot to do so. Also, it won't do much with the `$` anchor unless the entire string follows this format.

Comment: @caiosm1005: Yes you're right, that's another issue. Good point! Corrected the answer.

Comment: Yes, because regex is that complicated, even I did it wrong. You need to escape characters with special meanings as well or use Q/E mode. Answer was modified, hopefully with that try you get more luck.

Comment: problem was in start and end symbols. Thanks for help.

Comment: This regex wont match, see here: http://www.regex101.com/r/zE6eY3, just remove the trailing `$` to match at least the first occurrence.

Comment: @caiosm1005: You deserve a lot of credit for the final answer here ;)

Comment: @hakre No problem, regexes are too easy to oversight sometimes :)

Comment: How is the joke about regex? Now you have another problem? Or something alike? :)

Comment: if it is possible, can you also show how to select each block '<!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png|--><img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png" alt="***" title="***"  /><!--dle_image_end-->'

Comment: this is HTML, you should use HTML parser that knows comment nodes. Much easier. See "Best way to parse HTML with PHP" in google, it goes to a super Q&A here on stackoverflow. I might add some comment parser example later on, can't right now.

Answer (score 0):

This will match the paths you want

```
(?<=<!--dle_image_begin:)((?:(?!\|-->).)*)(?=|-->)
```

The first and the last parts (`(?<=<!--dle_image_begin:)` & `(?=|-->)` ) are so called "lookarounds" to check the string before/after.

For more explanations, see here: http://www.regex101.com/r/iS8lE5